# How to set weight of column widths in GXT?

Tags: gridview, gxt

Is it possible to set the 'weight' of columns on a Grid in GXT?  If so, how?

According to the Grid's Javadocs:

> 'Grid can resize columns based on a
>   "weight". As the width of the grid, or
>   columns change, the "weight" is used
>   to allocate the extra space, or the
>   space needed to be reduced.'

According to the docs, it says to set `GridView.setAutoFill(true)` to enable this feature, but doesn't mention anything about configuring the weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define them when you create your ColumnConfigs

```
private List<ColumnConfig> getColumnConfigs() {
  List<ColumnConfig> configs = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();

  ColumnConfig col1ColumnConfig = new ColumnConfig("col1", "Col1", 50);

  ColumnConfig col2ColumnConfig = new ColumnConfig("col2", "Col2", 75);

  configs.add(col1ColumnConfig );
  configs.add(col2ColumnConfig );
  return configs;
}

    ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(getColumnConfigs());
    worklistGrid = new Grid<BeanModel>(store, cm);
    worklistGrid.setAutoExpandColumn("col1"); //autoexpand
    final GridView view = new GridView();
    view.setAutoFill(true);
```

Comment: Thanks.  That sets the width.  I think the AutoFill property is different from the AutoExpand property...

Comment: The values are relative weights they're not actual pixel widths. If you turn of AutoFill they become actual pixel widths. This was the case with GWT-EXT and I believe it's the same in Ext-GWT. AutoExpand is unnecessary, I just put it there as an optional call I usually use.